# R/ Shiny - How to get current year with Sys.Date()?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I get current year with Sys.Date()?

I have this code below,

```
      selectInput(
        inputId = "year",
        label = "Year:",
        choices = c(2014:Sys.Date())
        )
```

result,

```
<select id="year"><option value="2014" selected>2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
....
<option value="16582">16582</option></select>
```

But I just need,

```
<select id="year">
    <option value="2014" selected>2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can just use the `format()` function here as outlined in the help page for `Sys.Date()`. See `?strptime` for all the different specifications:

```
> c(2014, format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))
[1] "2014" "2015"
```

If you actually need integer values, then:

```
> c(2014L, as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")))
[1] 2014 2015
```

Answer (score 8):

Couldn't you just do this:

```
choices = c(2014:lubridate::year(Sys.Date()))
```

using `lubridate` to get the year from `Sys.Date()`?

Comment: Thanks but I get this error `ERROR: there is no package called ‘lubridate`

Comment: @teelou - you need to install package lubridate with `install.pakcages("lubridate")`, or use a Base R function as suggested below.